# How do I show $x^2 \sin (\frac{1}{x})$ is differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis

If a function $f(x) = x^2 \sin (\frac{1}{x}), x \neq 0$ and $f(0) = 0$, how do I show this function is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}.$

--Edit

I have tried to find the limit when $x \neq 0$ and got this. The definition of the limit of a function is $f'(x) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}.$ So I got $f'(a) = \lim_{h \rightarrow0} \frac{a^2 (\sin(\frac{1}{a+h}) - \sin(\frac{1}{a}))}{h} = 0$ at $x = a,$ because as $h \rightarrow0$, $\sin(\frac{1}{a+h}) = \sin(\frac{1}{a}).$ Am I doing it right??

Comment: Away from zero, the differentiation rules apply.  At zero, start by writing down the difference quotient for the function.

Comment: To add to that: you can use the product and chain rules to explicitly find the derivative on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$. But at $0$, you'll have to use the definition of the derivative to prove it exists (make sure to evaluate the limit from both the negative side and the positive side).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have, at $x=0,$

$$f'(0)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{h^2\sin \frac{1}{h}}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0}h\sin \frac{1}{h}=0,$$

since $h$ goes to $0$ and $\sin \frac{1}{h}$ is bounded.

At any point $x\ne 0$ just apply the usual rules to get the derivative.

**Edit**

In a comment the OP asks for a proof of the fact that $f'$ is not continuous at $x=0.$

We have, using the useful rules to get the derivative, $f'(x)=2x\sin\frac1x-\cos\frac1x.$

We have $\lim_{x\to 0} 2x\sin \frac1x=0$ since $x$ goes to $0$ and $\sin \frac1x$ is bounded. However, $\lim_{x\to 0}\cos \frac1x$ doesn't exist. Why? Because $\frac1x$ goes to $\infty$ and the cosine function oscillates between $-1$ and $1$ without approaching any value.

Comment: It's $\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$, not $\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 You are right. I am going to correct the typo. Thank you very much.

Comment: The original problem is asking to show $f'$ is not continuous at $x=0$. Can u explain this too?

Comment: @mfl Can u check the added part above?? And thanks for your answer.

Comment: It is $f'(a) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(a+h)^2 \sin(\frac{1}{a+h}) -a^2 \sin(\frac{1}{a})}{h}$ which is not identically zero for any $a.$

Comment: @mfl What do you mean by "not identically zero for any a??" Is that mean the limit approaches to zero but not exactly zero?? $f(a+h) \approx f(a)$ as $h \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: You are right when you write $f(a+h) \approx f(a).$ But $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}=\frac{0}{0}$ (if $f$ is continuous) which is an indeterminate form. You have to compute it based on the particular definition of $f.$

Comment: @mfl thanks.. it was very helpful...^^